# Mysql query fetching record between two months

Tags: mysql, fetch

I am looking for query which fetch record between two months.
It looks simple but I am looking for a query which fetch record for two different months.

ie.

January and April

query should show result from the month of January and April but it should not show result for February and march.

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried? Provide your code, table you use, sample data and desired output ...etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * from table_name where month(date_field) = 1 or month(date_field) = 4
```

this will show all results for january and april, but for all years. to filter year, add another check in query

```
SELECT * from table_name where (month(date_field) = 1 or month(date_field) = 4) and year(date_field) = 2016
```

Comment: I have timestamp field. Will it work with timestamp or just work with date field?

Comment: Will it work with custom field. Like I have stored date and time in varchar field using php date() function?

Comment: Yes it is working, I have checked it, I also didn't know that it will work :)

Comment: But I would suggest to use Datetime field to save this data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM data where (data.createdAt BETWEEN "2016-01-01" AND "2016-01-31") OR (data.createdAt BETWEEN "2016-04-01" AND "2016-04-31")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.